# cesium load gltf not int the right position

Tags: cesiumjs, gltf

**cesium load gltf, not in the right position**

I'm trying to load a model of house, by cesium.  I have already set the position of the model by specified the matrix of the model, but the model is not in the position where I put it. I found the model origin is not in or near the model itself .

Someone suggested, modifying the `gltf` file, to make sure the origin is near or in the center of model should work, but how can this be done through programming?  I don't want to edit thousand `gltf` models.

Comment: What have you tried so far, coding wise?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some with this links will help:
https://cesium.com/docs/on-premise/tilers/models/
https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/Model

By the way, how bad is the wrong position? Are you sure that didn't inverted latitude and longitude?